# PSExec - Remotely Run Windows Process Over Long Distance

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, psexec, sysinternals

I am currently using psexec.exe (link here [PSExec Description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx)) in order to remotely run various processes on a certain machine at my company's office. I currently have this remote access working just fine on my office's local area network. All I have to do is specify the ipv4 local address of the remote machine and the correct username/password for the user.

My next goal is to allow computers which are not on the same local network to remotely start processes on this computer. That way, when I am at home on my own network, I can still use psexec to remotely run programs on this office computer.

My knowledge on this subject is admittedly on the lower end so I am not fully aware what my options are to achieve this. I am aware that port forwarding may be the best or only option. If this is the case, any fine details I should know would be appreciated (such as what port numbers I would need to use).

Thank you.

Comment: Psexec only works to computers who are connected to one network. Ill assume that your using a laptop, you may check RSA(remote access). RSA treats your laptop that it is connected to you network.